# Grunt - Wiredep Warning: "Must provide pattern"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I#m trying to get started using grunt together with bower to build my project. So right now i simply want to inject all my installed bower packages into my index.html file using the grunt plugin wiredep.

When i try to run the grunt command it always says:

> Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task
>   Warning: must provide pattern Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings. Done.

I have found other topics with the same error, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

This is my `grunfile`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        wiredep: {

            target: {
                src: '/public_html/index.html'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wiredep');

};
```

This is my `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "GeoSystem",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "/public_html/js/model.js",
  "ignore": [
    ".jshintrc",
    "**/*.txt"
  ],
  "dependencies": {"jQuery":"3.2.0",
    "arcgis-js-api": "4.3.0",
    "OpenLayers": "4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
</body>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: looks fine for me, are you sure that is as http://stephenplusplus.github.io/grunt-wiredep/?

Comment: Yes, i have installed it via `npm install grunt-wiredep --save-dev` like in the tutorial. I'm using netbeans 8.2 as my IDE if that somehow matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `arcgis-js-api`. Its bower.json does not provide a `main` field which causes an issue with `grunt-wiredep`.

https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep

You will need to exclude it from your grunt-wiredep target or override and provide an appropriate main if it is to be linked.